# How to make 'C4700: uninitialized local variable' be an error in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Well, that is my problem. I don't know how to achieve this in Release mode, as the compiler is not even issuing a warning (I do know how to force an error out of a warning--with the /we option). I have tried tweeking several options, including raising the warning level to ALL; I have google all I can and tried Microsoft's documentation on this warning, with no good outcome, and I have run out of ideas.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't configure only Debug mode in property pages?

Comment: @LogicStuff I'm not sure what you mean. In Debug mode a get a warning, which I know how to force into an error, but in Release mode I don't get a warning at any warning level. I don't know if there is a flag overriding that, a google search turned empty.

Comment: Are you using any third party libraries. Perhaps one of them is setting `#pragma warning( error : 4700 )`

Comment: Maybe it's not used in release. As in `int i; ASSERT(i == 1);`.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not using any third-party libs. Besides, that would also overshadow the warning in Debug mode, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. The pragma could be in an `#ifdef NDEBUG`

Comment: @MPortilheiro VS allows you to set separate set of options for Debug/Release. You switch between them in the property pages. Or are you using command line to compile?

Comment: @LogicStuff Ultimately, I will use the msbuild tool on the command line, yes. But for the moment, I am compiling directly on the IDE. And yes, I am being careful to set the options for each case, Debug or Release

Comment: Maybe the compiler is optimizing the code out in release builds and thus there is nothing left to issue warnings about. You could try explicitly using the variable in a `cout` statement to prevent it from being optimized out and see if you then get a warning. You could also try a newer compiler, VS2012 is pretty old.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's exactly what I am doing to try to trigger it, outputing an uninitialized `int` to stdout. I am also stuck with VS2012, that's what my company uses....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The issue was that this portion of the code was in one of several projects comprising my solution (this particular one generating a static lib), and in Release mode the 'Whole Program Optimization' is marked to 'Use Link Time Code Generation' by default (`/GL`). The error does manifest itself, but only at *link time*!! As I was just compiling the source, I didn't see it before.

I see this as shortcoming, but I guess the compiler will not know beforehand if that part of the code will be stripped. Still, could the compiler do a better job at detecting this earlier? My solution takes several minutes to compile, I only saw the error after that. The clue was that when I turned the Whole Program Optimization off, I saw the error right away.

Thanks for everyone's help.